# Unable to run exe created on my pc on other computers

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I created an exe file using py2exe(that contains media i.e images).it works fine on the computer i created the exe,but not on other computers. It raises a 'Failed to execute script' error.

Comment: Are the images stored on the computer you want to run it on? The exe file will look for a path to those images so the path must be identical on other computers

Answer (score 1):

you must include your file to build:

```
Mydata_files = [('images', ['c:/path/to/image/image.png'])]


setup(
    console = ['XXXXX'],
    data_files = Mydata_files,
    options = {
        "py2exe": {
        "unbuffered": True,
        "skip_archive": True,
        "optimize": 2
        }
    }
```

check official [site](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files)